# Korean charset in JJT file

Tags: java, parsing, unicode, javacc

I am trying to add korean character in a JJT file :

```
| < #XCHARSET :
        ("_latin" | "_unicode" | "_kanjisjis" | "_graphic" | "national" (<WHITESPACE>)+ ("character" | "char"))
        (<WHITESPACE>)*
       >
| < #XCHARSET2 :
        ("_latin" | "_unicode" | "_kanjisjis" | "_graphic" | "_kanji1")
        (<WHITESPACE>)*
       >
```

How to define korean character to this. I am new to parsing so I am not sure ho to add that in the charset.
Can someone please help. Do I have to add _korean or is there another keyword to it?

Comment: isn't it added by `_unicode` keyword?

Comment: What language is your parser for?

Comment: @TheodoreNorvell, it is for Teradata SQL.

Comment: @mangusta , I don't think so as it is giving the error.

Comment: So first off the document at http://teradata.weizheng.net/2012/08/character-sets-in-teradata.html suggests looking in a Teradata manual  "International Character Set Support". I couldn't find that document.

Comment: However I did find this (http://docplayer.net/48818155-Using-international-character-sets-with-sas-and-teradata.html) in which table 3 may be of use.  Note that Korean character sets can only be used for client character sets, not for server character sets.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try adding

```
options {
  UNICODE_INPUT=true;
}
```

to your header ?